# Socket.error: [Errno 10022] An invalid argument was supplied

Tags: python, sockets

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import socket
clientsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clientsocket.connect(('192.168.1.123', 5162))
clientsocket.send('getval.1')
clientsocket.close
clientsocket.bind(('192.168.1.124', 5163))
clientsocket.listen(1)
while True:
    connection, address=clientsocket.accept()
    value=connection.recv(1024)
    print value
```

I'm trying to get python to send a message to the server, and in return the server responds. Yet when I execute this code it gives me

```
Socket.error: [Errno 10022] An invalid argument was supplied
```

Comment: always show full error message (traceback). There are more usefull inforamtion. Which line makes problem ?

Comment: first you need `()` in `close()` to close it. Second: you can't use closed socket again - you have to create new socket. BTW: you could use the same connection to `send()` data to server and to `recv()` data from server - if you only change server too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you wrote a mixed code of server and client
Here a simple sample of codes for socket programming the first on server side and the second on client

> Server side code:

```
# server.py 
import socket                                         
import time

# create a socket object
serversocket = socket.socket(
            socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 

# get local machine name
host = socket.gethostname()                           

port = 9999                                           

# bind to the port
serversocket.bind((host, port))                                  

# queue up to 5 requests
serversocket.listen(5)                                           

while True:
    # establish a connection
    clientsocket,addr = serversocket.accept()      

    print("Got a connection from %s" % str(addr))
    currentTime = time.ctime(time.time()) + "\r\n"
    clientsocket.send(currentTime.encode('ascii'))
    clientsocket.close()
```

> and now the client

```
# client.py  
import socket

# create a socket object
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 

# get local machine name
host = socket.gethostname()                           

port = 9999

# connection to hostname on the port.
s.connect((host, port))                               

# Receive no more than 1024 bytes
tm = s.recv(1024)                                     

s.close()

print("The time got from the server is %s" % tm.decode('ascii'))
```

The server simply remained listened for any client and when it finds out a new connection it returns current datetime and closes the client connection